How to gain my cats trust back after a 4 day long vet visit?
Recently my cat has been feeling really bad. She stopped eating, using the litter box and was really asocial. We went to the vet but it got worse so we ended up going to another vet. They told us that she needs to stay in a pet hospital. She was there for 4 days and they diagnosed her with a heart disease. Since she came back she still hasn't started eating and she doesn't trust me or my mom. We have to give her meds twice a day which doesn't help us get her trust back. We tried snacks, giving her some space, getting closer to her slowly. Nothing seems to help. At this point we have no idea what to do. There are still some visits waiting for us and i'm scared that she won't trust us anytime soon, because of the disease she will have to see vets quite often. Is there a way to make her trust us? Should we give her even more space and not approach her too much? She has been home for 3 days. I know that that's a short time after such a traumatic experience but it's worrying since she won't eat anything and we have to give her something similar to nutridrinks.
